# How to implement Smart banner for Apple store/Google play

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

[image]

Hi,

I want to implement smart banner for apple store/google play in company website...Please anyone help me to fix this issue...

Thanks

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below you have the links that explains how to implement a Smart App Banner on your website.

[- IOS 6 and later](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)

[- Android and IOS 5 and previous](http://www.jasny.net/jquery.smartbanner/#android)

> Smart App Banners automatically determine whether the app is supported
>   on the user’s device. If the device loading the banner does not
>   support your app, or if your app is not available in the user's
>   location, the banner will not display.